# i am using excel.js for download the users list in to xlsx file but can't able to convert the blob into readable file

Tags: express, mern, exceljs

the api getting the users but when i implment the api in to the front-end the response.data is undefined i tried many times but the result is same

i want to try to download the user data into excel sheet and i am using excelJs but did't able to do so so i need help form experts to guide me or suggest me more easy way to download the users data in xlsx

nodejs api

```
 export const getUserCSV = async (req, res) => {
  try {
     const users = await User.find({});

     const workbook = new exceljs.Workbook();

     const sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("users");

      const header = [
      { header: "Username", key: "userName", width: 20 },
      { header: "First Name", key: "firstName", width: 20 },
      { header: "Last Name", key: "lastName", width: 20 },
      { header: "Email", key: "email", width: 20 },
      { header: "Role", key: "role", width: 20 },
       ];

       sheet.columns = header;

      users.forEach((user) => {
       sheet.addRow(user.toObject()); // Ensure each user is converted to a plain object
       });

        sheet.getRow(1).eachCell((cell) => {
        cell.font = { bold: true };
      });

      // Set response headers
     res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
     res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=users.csv");

     // Convert workbook to CSV and send as plain text
     workbook.csv
  .writeBuffer()
  .then((buffer) => {
    res.send(buffer.toString());
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  });
   } catch (error) {
   console.error("Error exporting users:", error);
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
   };
```

front end implmentation

```
    const handleExport = async () => {
     fetch("/api/user/get-user-csv")
      .then((response) => response.text())
       .then((data) => {
         console.log(data); // Log the received data to the console
         if (data !== undefined) {
           const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });
           fileSaver.saveAs(blob, "users.xlsx");
         } else {
          console.error("Error: CSV data is undefined");
         }
        })
       .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error downloading CSV:", error);
        });
     };
```